# Display all "assigned to me" work items of all collections of a TFS server inside a unique dashboard or inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am using TFS 2017 Update 1, installed on a Windows server machine.

Is it possible to display all "assigned to me" work items of all collections of a TFS server inside a unique dashboard or inside Visual Studio ?

For example, the TFS server web site allows to display all "assigned to me" work items of a collection.

So :

- Is there a parent page inside TFS server web site, that allows to display all "assigned to me" work items of all collections ?
- Is there also a way to display all "assigned to me" work items from the startup menu for example ?

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Team Project collections are intended to be totally isolated instances. There is no reporting across team project collection boundaries. The intended use-case for Team Project Collections is to allow hosting of multiple "instances" of TFS from one central server. For example, an organization with many totally independent subsidiaries that do not share code or employees would have a perfect scenario for multiple team project collections. Most organizations require only a single team project collection.

You can take advantage of the [REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview) to write whatever sort of custom data aggregation script your heart desires.